# HandlerThread: Only one Looper may be created per thread

Tags: android, handler

This is a quite common problem using android looper, but it is very strange that I am using HandlerThread, and I never invoke Looper.prepare. No idea why this happens.

The whole crash log is below:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: process_network1
>
> at com.xiaomi.smarthome.library.common.util.MessageHandlerThread.run(MessageHandlerThread.java:43)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
>
> at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:92)
>
> at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:87)
>
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:54)
>
> at com.xiaomi.smarthome.library.common.util.MessageHandlerThread.run(MessageHandlerThread.java:40)

The MessageHandlerThread is below:

```
public class MessageHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {

private static final int DUR_TIME = 2 * 60 *60 *1000;
private static final int MSG_EMPTY_MSG = 1;
private Handler mHandler;
public MessageHandlerThread(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public MessageHandlerThread(String name, int priority) {
    super(name, priority);
}

void init() {
    mHandler = new Handler(this.getLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_EMPTY_MSG, DUR_TIME);
        }
    };

    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_EMPTY_MSG, DUR_TIME);
}

@Override
public synchronized void start() {
    super.start();
    init();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        super.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(getName(), e);
    }
}
}
```

It crashes in the "*super.run()*;" Why this happens? Seems  entering run twice? I absolutely never call "*thread.run()*"

Answer (score 0):

`HandlerThread` is extending `Thread` class.

When you create a class that extends `Thread`, you call `start` method, not `run` method. This indicates the `run` method will be called by `start` method internally.

Just remove `super.run()` statement, solves your problem.

You can do it without extending `HandlerThread` class like below.

```
HandlerThread messageHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("MessageHandlerThread");
messageHandlerThread.start();

Handler handler = new Handler(messageHandlerThread.getLooper());
handler.post(<<YOUR_RUNNABLE>>);
```

Comment: Hi, in HandlerThread's run, there are some initialization such as looper.prepare, notifyAll, etc, and the run() method is called asynchronously when call start(). Is it a good idea not invoking the super.run?

Comment: Yes. If you go to the implementation details of `Looper.prepare`, they are checking for `sThreadLocal.get() != null` which means if `Looper.prepare` method called more than once, they will raise `RuntimeException` with `Only one Looper may be created per thread`. So, it is not supposed to call `super.run()` again in `run`.

Comment: Yes, it sounds a solution for this problem, I'll try this. I just have no idea why the run enters again.

Comment: @mianlaoshu, you are calling that method again with your `super.run()` statement in your code.

Comment: I just added if(Looper.myLooper() != null) return; to prevent such crash. There is no more crash then